# Websphere Liberty profile - ant tasks for jsp and ejbs

Tags: ant, websphere-liberty

I am pretty new to websphere liberty profile.
Does liberty provides ant tasks to compile jsps and ejbs?
The same is available in full profile and we are using those targets to build our application.
For example for jsp compilation class name is `(com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.jspC)` and for ejb task class name `(com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy)` . I am not finding those in liberty profile. We see only target related to server, deploy and undeploy in `wlp-anttasks.jar`.
Do we need to build the application outside of liberty profile and only deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Liberty profile does not provide a way to precompile JSPs.  IBM might support binaries that use the JSP batch compiler from the full profile, but that support is not documented, so I would recommend asking IBM support first.

As an alternative, you could try specifying the prepareJSPs attribute in ibm-web-ext.xml.  See the [Configuring JSP engine parameters](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jspengine.html) and [Pre-touch tool for compiling and loading JSP files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_pretouch.html) topics in the knowledge center for more information.  Note that this option will cause the JSPs to be compiled when the application is first started, which is not quite the same as precompiling since the JSPs will be recompiled each time the application is redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario of pre-compiling JSP files in Full Profile with the JspBatchCompiler then dropping them in to Liberty is not supported.  There are some differences between the translated JSP files in Full Profile and Liberty that I think could cause problems in more complex environments / applications.

The workaround / solution to not having a JspBatchCompiler in Liberty was already posted by bkail.  Which is to set prepareJSPs=0.  This will cause Liberty to compile all the JSPs when the application is started (by default, on first request).  Also, you can add the deferServletLoad=false to load/start the application at Liberty startup, effectively causing all the JSPs to be compiled then instead of at first request.